# unable to fetch data from DB

Tags: android, json, database

I've a sample JSON as given below:

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": "a200",
      "question": "lorem ipsum dolor _______ amet",
      "optionA": "lorem",
      "optionB": "ipsum",
      "optionC" : "dolor",
      "optionD": "sit",
      "rightAnswer" : "sit"

    },
    {
      "id": "b200",
      "question": "_____ ipsum dolor sit amet",
      "optionA": "lorem",
      "optionB": "ipsum",
      "optionC" : "dolor",
      "optionD": "sit",
      "rightAnswer" : "lorem"

    },
    {
      "id": "c200",
      "question": "lorem _____ dolor sit amet",
      "optionA": "lorem",
      "optionB": "ipsum",
      "optionC" : "dolor",
      "optionD": "sit",
      "rightAnswer" : "ipsum"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm inserting above JSON to a table in DB. Code for that is as given below:

```
package com.emc.kulkaa.learner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

/**
 * Created by kulkaa on 2/13/2018.
 */

public class ParseAction {
    SQLiteDatabase SQLITEDATABASE;
    private Context context;

    public ParseAction(Context context, SQLiteDatabase SQLITEDATABASE) {
        this.context = context;
        this.SQLITEDATABASE = SQLITEDATABASE;
        putData();
        /*fetchData();*/
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("questions.json");
            int size = inputStream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }

    public void putData() {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("questions");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL(String.format("INSERT INTO quesTable ( id, question, option1, option2, option3, option4, rightAnswer ) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Arrays.toString(new Object[]{
                        jsonObject.getString("id"),
                        jsonObject.getString("question"),
                        jsonObject.getString("optionA"),
                        jsonObject.getString("optionB"),
                        jsonObject.getString("optionC"),
                        jsonObject.getString("optionD"),
                        jsonObject.getString("rightAnswer")
                })));

                Log.d(TAG, "putData: " + jsonObject.getString("id"));
                Log.d(TAG, "putData: " + jsonObject.getString("question"));
                Log.d(TAG, "putData: " + jsonObject.getString("optionA"));
                Log.d(TAG, "putData: " + jsonObject.getString("optionB"));
                Log.d(TAG, "putData: " + jsonObject.getString("optionC"));

            }


        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Log.d prints `putData` as given below:

```
02-14 09:15:17.751 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: a200
02-14 09:15:17.751 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: lorem ipsum dolor _______ amet
02-14 09:15:17.751 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: lorem
02-14 09:15:17.751 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: ipsum
02-14 09:15:17.751 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: dolor
02-14 09:15:17.755 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: b200
02-14 09:15:17.755 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: _____ ipsum dolor sit amet
02-14 09:15:17.755 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: lorem
02-14 09:15:17.755 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: ipsum
02-14 09:15:17.755 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: dolor
02-14 09:15:17.759 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: c200
02-14 09:15:17.759 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: lorem _____ dolor sit amet
02-14 09:15:17.759 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: lorem
02-14 09:15:17.759 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: ipsum
02-14 09:15:17.759 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/ContentValues: putData: dolor
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve the data and show it in UI. My code for fetching data isn't working. Code is as given below:

```
package com.emc.kulkaa.learner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase SQLITEDATABASE;
    ArrayList<questionDataPOJO> questionList;

    private static String TAG = QuizActivity.class.getCanonicalName();

    /*
     * Keep bottom 10% for branding
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        context = this;

        SQLITEDATABASE = openOrCreateDatabase("QuizDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quesTable(id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
                " question VARCHAR, option1 VARCHAR, option2 VARCHAR, option3 VARCHAR, option4 VARCHAR, rightAnswer VARCHAR);");

        ParseAction parseAction = new ParseAction(this, SQLITEDATABASE);

        questionList = new ArrayList<>();

        fetchData();

    }


    private void fetchData() {
        Cursor cursor = SQLITEDATABASE.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM quesTable", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            do {
                questionList.add(new questionDataPOJO(
                        cursor.getString(0), // id
                        cursor.getString(1), // ques
                        cursor.getString(2), // A
                        cursor.getString(3), // B
                        cursor.getString(4), // C
                        cursor.getString(5)  // D
                ));
                Log.d(TAG, "id is " + cursor.getString(0));
                Log.d(TAG, "Question is " + cursor.getString(1));
                Log.d(TAG, "Option A is " + cursor.getString(2));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Log.d returns values for id, but values for `Question`, `OptionA` etc are null. It is as given below:

```
02-14 09:15:17.761 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/com.emc.kulkaa.learner.QuizActivity: id is 1
02-14 09:15:17.762 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/com.emc.kulkaa.learner.QuizActivity: Question is null
02-14 09:15:17.762 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/com.emc.kulkaa.learner.QuizActivity: Option A is null
02-14 09:15:17.762 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/com.emc.kulkaa.learner.QuizActivity: id is 2
02-14 09:15:17.762 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/com.emc.kulkaa.learner.QuizActivity: Question is null
02-14 09:15:17.762 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/com.emc.kulkaa.learner.QuizActivity: Option A is null
02-14 09:15:17.762 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/com.emc.kulkaa.learner.QuizActivity: id is 3
02-14 09:15:17.762 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/com.emc.kulkaa.learner.QuizActivity: Question is null
02-14 09:15:17.762 13807-13807/com.emc.kulkaa.learner D/com.emc.kulkaa.learner.QuizActivity: Option A is null
```

How can I fix it?
**EDIT:**
I'm using a POJO class as given below:

```
public class questionDataPOJO {
    String id, question, optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, rightAnswer;

    public questionDataPOJO(String id, String question, String optionA, String optionB, String optionC,
                            String optionD) {
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        this.optionA = optionA;
        this.optionB = optionB;
        this.optionC = optionC;
        this.optionD = optionD;
        this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String getOptionA() {
        return optionA;
    }

    public String getOptionB() {
        return optionB;
    }

    public String getOptionC() {
        return optionC;
    }

    public String getOptionD() {
        return optionD;
    }

    public String getRightAnswer() {
        return rightAnswer;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public void setOptionA(String optionA) {
        this.optionA = optionA;
    }

    public void setOptionB(String optionB) {
        this.optionB = optionB;
    }

    public void setOptionC(String optionC) {
        this.optionC = optionC;
    }

    public void setOptionD(String optionD) {
        this.optionD = optionD;
    }

    public void setRightAnswer(String rightAnswer) {
        this.rightAnswer = rightAnswer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will tell u what I do. I parse my JSON, and put it in a modal's constructor, store it in DB using Room persistence library.
There are many advantages in using this library, it will  let you know the errors in compile time, you wont get cursor errors, you needn't write cursor code, also the code looks structured.

Comment: If you're setting the ID from the JSON, it shouldn't be `AUTOINCREMENT` in the table. And that should be `INTEGER`, not `VARCHAR`. On the other hand, if it is supposed to be defined by the `AUTOINCREMENT` table ID, then you shouldn't be inserting it. Also, that `String.format()` call is wrong. The `?` character doesn't mean anything special for that method, so none of your arguments are inserted there. Instead, use the `execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)` method, and just drop the `String.format()` call.

Comment: @Raul: any idea how can I do that?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni yes, browse these : JSON parsing, i hope u already knew to parse json. See tutorials on Room persistence  DB. https://github.com/tb-yangshu/AndroidRoomLibExample this sample is good.

Comment: @Raul: Thank you, I'll check that sample. Is it possible to fix current code for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please defined your Initialize ArrayList type.

```
questionList = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
questionList = new ArrayList< questionDataPOJO >();
```

Comment: That doesn't do much, buddy